# WinUI3 wait cursor after startup

Tags: winui-3

If you start a winui3 app (including the controls gallery) and don't move the mouse, it will show a busy spinning cursor until you move the mouse.

Does anyone have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, this issue is reproducible with the WinUI 3 Gallery app. Actually there's an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/issues/1012) filed on the GitHub repo but without a workaround.

I just found a workaround by setting focus on the `AutoSuggestBox` on the left.

```cs
private void OnNavigationViewControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Delay necessary to ensure NavigationView visual state can match navigation
    Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ => this.NavigationViewLoaded?.Invoke(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    // Set focus just as a workaround for the "waiting mode cursor" at startup.
    this.controlsSearchBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```

Comment: too bad the issue's in the wrong repo.

Comment: I'm currently scanning the issues on the WinUI repo but with can't find anything similar so far. I'll post an issue if I don't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The issue now also [in the correct repository](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8689), the one for Windows App SDK, referencing the [original issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/issues/1012) that was raised for the Win-UI Gallery repository.  There is a fix for it "in the WASDK 1.5 timeframe".